# How to implement fixed point operations without Fixed Point Designer Library in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I am supposed to work with an existing code in my work and at some places the previous programmer has extensively used Fimath function. Unfortunately, I am not having the license for the Fixed Point Designer toolbox and was looking for some alternatives.

I tried getting the fimath.m file from another source but it is referencing to some embedded libraries in the toolbox.

Is there some other way in which I can bypass this problem?

Thank You

Comment: Matlab fixed point can use 128bit, if such word length are used it's nearly impossible because your Matlab supports at most uint64.